# Using 2D array of pointers leads to error

Tags: c++

I have something like the follow:

```
template<class T>
struct point{
   point* next = nullptr;
   T* data = nullptr;
}

template<class T>
class newClass
{
   point<T>*** points;

public:
   newClass()
   {
      points = new point<T>**[10];
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
          points[i] = new point<T>*[10];

      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
          for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
             if(j != 9)
                points[i][j]->next = points[i][j+1]; //ERROR
   }
};
```

Can someone help me understand why this produces an error? I don't receive an error message, the program just crashes.

Comment: Please don't be [Three Star Programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: Why not just use `std::vector` *et al* rather than re-inventing the wheel ?

Comment: Why make a simple linked list of the nodes, when you already have all of them in a container? You already know that the "next" node of `points[a][b]` will be `points[a][b+1]`.

Comment: points[i][j] is not initialized

Answer (score 3):

When you do `points[i][j]->next` you dereference an uninitialized pointer which leads to *undefined behavior*.

Drop one level of indirection and do

```
points[i][j].next = &points[i][j+1];
```

Or, do an extra allocation loop to initialize that last pointer too.

---

For a different way, you don't need to use pointers at all here, especially since your allocations are all of a fixed size, which means you can use fixed arrays, or even better, [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

```
std::array<std::array<point<T>, 10>, 10> points;
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of expression

```
points[i][j]
```

is `point<T> *`. This pointer was not initialized. It has indertermined value.  At first you need to allocate an object that will be pointed to by this pointer. For example

```
points[i][j] = new point<t>();
```

Otherwise this

```
points[i][j]->next
```

refers nowhere.

I think you mean the following

```
template<class T>
class newClass
{
   point<T> **points;

public:
   newClass()
   {
      points = new point<T>*[10];
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
          points[i] = new point<T>[10]();

      for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                points[i]->next = points[i+1];
   }
};
```

Comment: Isn't points[i] and array of points? If points[i] has 10 elements, I want each of them to have a "next" basically.

Comment: @KalibiddJlddkO I am sorry. I have not understood what you asked. Do you need a one-dimensional array of dynamically allocated objects of type point<T> or do you need a two-dimensional array of dynamically allocated objects of type point<T>?

Answer (score 0):

You have too many pointer operators. The code below will work...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
struct point {
    point* next = nullptr;
    T* data = nullptr;
    T* operator->() {
        return data;
    }
};

template<class T>
class newClass
{
    point<T>** points;

public:
    newClass()
    {
        points = new point<T>*[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            points[i] = new point<T>[10];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                if (j != 9) {
                    points[i][j].next = points[i][j + 1].next; //ERROR
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    newClass<int> nc;

    return 0;
}
```